# Initialize 64 by 64 numpy of (0,0) tuples in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types, pre-allocation

Is it possible to create a numpy of any arbitrary data structure, for example tuples? If yes, how do I initialize it without writing it out? (Obviously, I don't want to write out 64 by 64 array)

Comment: A structured array of tuples can be created as https://stackoverflow.com/a/63813720/9698684 too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way:

```
value = np.empty((), dtype=object)
value[()] = (0, 0)
a = np.full((64, 64), value, dtype=object)
```

Some trickery is required here to ensure that numpy does not try to iterate the tuple, hence the initial wrapping in an object array

Comment: line 3 in full ValueError: setting an element with a sequence

Comment: @AlexAzazel: Oops, good catch - missed the dtype. [Eventually, this won't be required](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L299-L301)

Answer (score 2):

Create an empty array of `dtype=object`:

```
a=np.empty((64,64), dtype=object)
```

then put tuples (or anything else) in it:

```
for y in range(64):
    for x in range(64):
        a[y,x] = (0,0)
```

The most import thing actually is the `dtype=object`, allowing you to put any Python object in it (losing the speed of vectorized operations however).

Comment: How does that compare with `a.fill((0,0))`?

Comment: @hpaulj You are right, if all values are to be the same, `a.fill` is convenient. I was focusing more on the `dtype=object` flag in my answer than to the way of filling the array.