# NumPy array initialization with tuple (fill with identical tuples)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I would like to create an array which is filled with identical tuples initially, specifically with tuples of `NaN`.
E.g.,

```
array([[(nan, nan), (nan, nan)],
       [(nan, nan), (nan, nan)],
       [(nan, nan), (nan, nan)]], dtype=object)
```

However, when using the array initialisations listed e.g. [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.array-creation.html) with an iterable value as value for filling in array, `python` apparently tries to reshape that iterable into the new array rather than fill it with it:

```
np.full([3,2],(np.nan,np.nan,np.nan),dtype=tuple)
#ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (3,2)
```

`np.fill` does not work either, it requires a scalar.

Is it only possible to fill the array item by item?

Comment: Provide provide code in the question, instead of providing link, or provide an explicit link to the code itself

Comment: What do you actually intend to do with those tuples?  The accepted answer didn't actually fill the array with tuples.  It made a structured array, which displays elements as tuples.  And when dealing with object arrays as you tried, there's a difference between 'identical tuples' and the 'same tuple'.

Comment: @hpaulj it is an initialisation for an array whose elements will contain maximum floating point value within an array of tuples of the same shape. So yes, it's identical, if I understand correctly and 'same' would mean reference to one single tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, with the correct `dtype`. With `'f,f'` you can initialise the array with tuples of `floats`; see [Data type objects (dtype)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) for more.

```
np.full((3,2), np.nan, dtype='f,f')

array([[(nan, nan), (nan, nan)],
       [(nan, nan), (nan, nan)],
       [(nan, nan), (nan, nan)]], dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
```

Comment: Thanks - it's probably a different issue, but then elements within the tuples are not `np.nan` anymore, `A[0,0][0] is np.nan` returns false? Although `math.isnan ` returns true.

Comment: that is because `np.nan!=np.nan` (try it). You need to use `np.isnan(A[0,0][0])` @joce

Comment: Thanks - I had seen syntax `is np.nan` elsewhere, but I realise now how wrong it is - means "is the same memory object".